# session_id() in PHP

Tags: php

I am just trying the `session_id` function in PHP and I thought that it was unique for each machine that used the website? However, my flatmate and I have the same `session_id` for on two separate machines. I'm just using `session_id()` to create the session - am I doing it correctly?

Comment: Are you talking about the session ID or your IP address? Are you initializing the session using `session_start`?

Comment: I initialize using session_start(); then use session_id() to (hopefully) create a unique session id

Comment: Can you post an example of identical session IDs? They definitely shouldn't be identical on two different machines. Can you show some code?

Comment: At the top of the page it goes like this;
session_start();
if(session_id=="")
{
 session_id('myses'.md5(microtime()));
}

Comment: You are missing the () in  the 1st session_id call, and I'm not really sure what you want to achieve with this. Isn't the session ID automatically provided by PHP random enough?

Answer (score 1):

Try creating your session like they do [here](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/phpsessions.php)

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `()` in your session_id call.

Also remember that you need to call `session_id()` **before** `session_start()` if you want to use it to set a specific session ID. From the [Manual](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php):

> If id  is specified, it will replace the current session id. session_id() needs to be called before session_start() for that purpose. Depending on the session handler, not all characters are allowed within the session id. For example, the file session handler only allows characters in the range a-z A-Z 0-9 , (comma) and - (minus)!

Answer (score 0):

Another idea is to store a value in the Session.

Comment: How is that related to the OP's problem? I don't understand.

Comment: If the Session doesn't have values, I wouldn't expect it to keep the SessionID either.  The session IDs may very well be unique if no one else is using that ID.